# Regarding login sample fails and also using syncronizing timer

Tags: jmeter

iam using an “Result status Action Handler” to stop the thread which fails to login also Iam using synchronising timer.for example
Users :20
If two users failed to login.it will not continue the execution because i have given result status to stop thread.but i have also given 20 users in the synchronising time.I need to hold the users to until every users logged in and only further execution should be started

Conditions:

1. I need to hold the users until every users logged in to continue further execution
2. Also i need to stop the thread which fails to login.
   How can do this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue attempting to log in with 20 users until every login is successful you can put the request under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter) and come up with an appropriate [function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which will return `false` when the login succeeds.

Stopping the thread in case of error is not the best idea because the Synchronizing Timer won't work on the next iteration as it will expect 20 users to be online and if at least one fails it will either wait forever or quit by timeout. Also if the thread is stopped it won't be able to retry the login request.